# How did native Australians arrive at the continent 65000 years ago?

Tags: aboriginals

[How did native Australians arrive at the continent 65000 years ago?](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nature22968) If by crossing the seas either from Africa or from South Asia, how did they navigate? How advanced might have been their knowledge of maritime navigation? Could they have followed the Sea turtles along the major ocean currents if they were a seafaring civilization?

Comment: Welcome to Hist SE, Harish. Have you checked the Wikipedia article [Indigenous Australians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigenous_Australians#Migration_to_Australia)? There are links there to other pages which should answer your question.

Comment: This might interest you - [*Island-hopping study shows the most likely route the first people took to Australia*](https://phys.org/news/2018-04-island-hopping-route-people-australia.html) (2018).

Comment: It seems that the answer to this question is simply unknown. There is no archeological evidence about navigation in that period. One can only speculate about it.

Comment: Additionally to the above comments I may add that the sea level was lower back then, which also allowed humans to cross the pacific over the Bering strait. So probably there were more and bigger islands on the way from Asia to Australia than now.